# Does ADFS3.0 provide custom authentication stores in SQL DB?

Tags: windows, authentication, windows-server-2012, saml-2.0, adfs

I have got the following Article from Microsoft

> For the Windows Server Technical Preview, the AD FS server role includes the same functionality and feature set that is available in Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2. It also includes new features that enable you to configure AD FS to authenticate users stored in non-AD directories, such as X.500 compliant Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) directories and SQL databases. In many organizations, identity management solutions consist of a combination of Active Directory, AD LDS and third-party LDAP directories, as well as SQL databases. With the AD FS support of the non-AD identity stores, you can benefit from the entire enterprise-ready AD FS feature set regardless of where your user identities are stored. For more information, see Configure AD FS to authenticate users stored in LDAP directories

My question is how can I create custom authentication stores in SQL DB?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about ADFS 3.0 but the quote refers to ADFS vNext?

If the question is "Does ADFS3.0 provide custom authentication stores in SQL DB", the answer in No.

ADFS 3.0 only authenticates against AD.

Comment: No the quote about authentications , note " It also includes new features that enable you to configure AD FS to authenticate users stored in non-AD directories, such as X.500 compliant Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) directories and SQL databases."

Comment: thanks nzpcmad 
but this quote is exist in windows server 2012 R2 :
check the follwing url :
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831502.aspx

Comment: The section that it appears under is "AD FS in Windows Server Technical Preview" - that's NOT 2012 R2 - that's ADFS vNext